# How can i make each element of a two dimensional array an object in python?

Tags: javascript, python, pygame

Im doing the game Brick breaker in pygame, i already did this game using canvas in javascript.

In javascript i initialized the bricks like this:

```
var bricks = [];
for(var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
  bricks[c] = [];
  for(var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
    bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0, status: 2 };
  }
}
```

Now i want to do the same in python but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: Better search for basic Python tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `Brick` class (or use dictionaries instead) and then append empty lists to `bricks` in the first `for` loop and append the `Brick` instances to the rows (lists) in the nested `for` loop.

```
class Brick:

    def __init__(self, x, y, status):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.status = status


brick_row_count = 4
brick_column_count = 3

bricks = []
for r in range(brick_row_count):
    bricks.append([])
    for c in range(brick_column_count):
        bricks[r].append(Brick(0, 0, 2))
```